# Unable to install the linux kernel

Tags: linux, boot, installation, partitioning, grub

I downloaded the Linux kernel version 3.6.10 from http://kernel.org. I was on an Ubuntu Linux when I opened the `.tar` file to a separate partition of 30GB. My ideal aim is to have my current Ubuntu Linux in one partition and the new Linux in another partition.

I did a `make` and `make install` on the new `linux` directory. It writes additions into the main GRUB. When I choose the OS from the GRUB menu during booting, I see the Linux birds two of them in the left corner of my screen. and the screen scrolls. It looks like it is installing, but at some point, the scroll seems to repeat itself continuously as if to go into a loop and will not stop. No installation takes place.

What should I expect on the screen as information/message stating installation is complete?

I use a Dell core 2 duo mobile laptop.

Comment: Curious what is the reason for installing a vanilla kernel?

Comment: i like to install and learn different OS. I already have the windows and ubuntu loaded. just tried my hand at this one and got stuck.

Comment: Ok, but you'll need more than just the kernel there. At least libc (etc.) and a shell.  Also, when you "make install" it installs into /boot. That's where the "real" kernel is. You want it in another location, with another runtime? BTW, I recommend using a virtual machine to do this.

Comment: and thats not how you make a kernel. iirc you need make menuconfig for example. I really suggest reading the Linux from scratch docs

Comment: My aim was to achieve the bash prompt of # after installing and booting the kernel, and then load GNOME for a desktop. and other software if necessary. I thought I made good progress seeing the two birds in the left hand corner, but the installation kept scrolling and seemed like in a loop.

Comment: @IanDSouza : The loop you see is not an installation process, it simply the kernel not knowing what to do. You'll to install more stuff manually (from your Ubuntu) to have something working. If you want to do all this by hand, check out Gentoo or even Linux From Scratch.

Comment: Right Levans, I shall. and thanks for the information. I definitely will have more posts. Am rusty at this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you really want is a minimal or command-line install. If you are comfortable with ubuntu, I would suggest the [minimal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD) or [server](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server) install options. Minimal requires network, server doesn't. Either will give you a barebones command line only install that you can build from there.

Answer (score 1):

Installing the Linux kernel alone won't give you a new OS. The kernel is only the core component around which Linux distributions are built.

At startup the kernel will load itself, and when ready it'll try to launch a process : `init`, which will then start all other processes of your OS, provided by your distribution. ([More details on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init))

In your case, you only installed the kernel alone. There is nothing else for it to start, so it does nothing.

If your goal is to try other Linux distributions, there are a lot of existing ones. You can have a look at Debian, Fedora, Archlinux, Gentoo...

You can check Wikipedia again, for more detailed info about what is a distribution : [here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution)

Comment: As Levans hints without a window manager or something similar the linux kernel by itself is sort of useless by itself.

Comment: I understand the Linux kernel is only the core component. Thats what I wanted to install and then other softwares available like GNOME, GTK+ etc. My aim was to arrive at the bash prompt.